# Probability of the simultaneous failure of two components where one component would take the full load if only one failed instead.

Tags: probability

Working through an example question in *Applied Probability for Engineers and Scientists*, 1st Ed., by Ephraim Suhir.

Example 1.9, beginning on p. 5, reads as follows:

> A heavy, nondeformable beam is fastened to a ceiling by means of two
>   parallel brittle rods. The weight $G$ of the beam is distributed
>   evenly between the rods if none of them failed, and is transmitted
>   completely to one of the rods if the other one failed. Determine the
>   probability of non-failure and the probability of failure of the
>   entire structure.

Define: $P_{1/2}$ as the probability of a rod failing under a load of $G/2$ and $P_1$ as the probability of a rod failing under a load of $G$. *The assumption is also made that the two rods are identical.

I had no problem obtaining the first requested probability:

$$P(\text{non-failure})=P(\text{neither fails})+P(\text{one rod fails, other rod can hold load of G})$$

$$P(\text{non-failure})=(1-P_{1/2})(1-P_{1/2})+2!P_{1/2}(1-P_1)$$

$$P(\text{non-failure})=1+P_{1/2}^2-2P_{1/2}P_1$$

For the second requested probability, the quickest way to obtain it would be to subtract the first obtained probability from 1:

$$P(\text{failure of entire structure})=1-P(\text{non-failure})$$

$$P(\text{failure of entire structure})=1-(1+P_{1/2}^2-2P_{1/2}P_1)$$

$$P(\text{failure of entire structure})=2P_{1/2}P_1-P_{1/2}^2$$

The above is the way the author does it, and he leaves it at that. However, just as an exercise, I wanted to attempt to deduce and confirm the probability of failure of the entire structure from the premises of the problem, similar to the way I computed the first requested probability. My attempt went as follows:

$$P(\text{failure of entire structure})=P(\text{both rods fail simultaneously})+P(\text{one rod fails under load of G/2, other fails under load of G})$$

$$P(\text{failure of entire structure})=P_{1/2}P_{1/2}+2!P_{1/2}P_1$$

$$P(\text{failure of entire structure})=P_{1/2}^2+2P_{1/2}P_1$$

Clearly, this result is not equivalent to the one obtained earlier. I have tried to figure out why the two methods give different results to no avail. My guess is that it has something to do with the fact that $P(\text{both rods fail simultaneously})$ requires them to fail at *exactly* the same instant, which would be different from two independent events that can occur one after the other.

Any enlightenment would be much appreciated.

Comment: There is something puzzling about the first solution. We have non-failure if neither beam fails, or one fails and the other holds.  The probability exactly one fails is $2P_{1/2}(1-P_{1/2})$, and not $2P_{1/2}$.   If $P_{1/2}$ is small, the $2P_{1/2}$ gives a reasonable first-order approximation.

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear how you're modelling the behaviour of the rod that holds under $G/2$ and is then supposed to carry the entire load. You didn't include the factor of $1-P_{1/2}$ for the rod holding under $G/2$ in the cases where the other one fails, but you did where the other one holds. I think the most lucid way of clearing up this confusion would be to add factors of $1-P_{1/2}$ also when the other one fails. That would make the probabilities add up to $1$, and it would allow $P_{1/2}$ to be consistently interpreted as the probability of the rod failing under $G/2$, but $P_1$ would then have to be interpreted as the conditional probability of a rod failing under $G$ given that it held under $G/2$, which is not what you introduced it as.

Answer (score 0):

To me both proposed results seem wrong. With $P_{1/2}=:p'$, $P_1=:p\>$ I argue as follows: The probability that neither of the two rods fails is $(1-p')^2$. Therefore with probability $2p'-p'^2$ we shall see the failure of a first rod, and then the second rod will fail as well with probability $p$. The probability $F$ that the beam will fall to the floor some day is therefore given by
$$F=p(2p'-p'^2)\ ,$$
and the probability $N$ of this not happening is $1-F$.